# Proving that any digraph that contains a closed directed walk of length at least one contains a directed cycle

Tags: graph-theory

Statement: Any digraph that contains a closed directed walk of length at least one contains a directed cycle

Is the proof as simple as using the definition of a closed walk? A walk is closed if the starting vertex is the same as the ending vertex. Therefore a closed directed walk of length at least one is a directed cycle of length one.

Comment: Isn't it just the definition of containing a directed cycle?

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate on that? Not sure what you mean by "definition of containing a directed cycle".

Comment: What is your definition of a cycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Directed closed walks can reuse edges and vertices, directed cycles may not.

However, it's still not a difficult proof.  Since there are directed close walks, by the well-ordering of the natural numbers we may choose a directed closed walk of minimal length.  This could not have any duplicated vertices, because otherwise we could cut out the overlap and make a shorter directed closed walk.  Therefore, that minimal length directed closed walk must be a directed cycle.